# Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and $B$ be a positive semi-definite matrix. Then $AB$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

> Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and $B$ be a positive
>    semi-definite matrix. Then $AB$ is diagonalizable.

I want to see if this is true or false.

Comment: There is information available at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about what we look for in posts on this site. This post currently lacks source and motivation - where did the problem arise, and why do you want to solve it?  You can improve the post by editing it.

Comment: @CarlMummert Can I ask if a statement is true or not? I am not sure if my statement is true.

Comment: You can definitely ask whether it is true or not - the current post seems to claim it is true, although I think it is not. But if you are asking if something is true or not, you should explain how you came upon the question - what were you looking at when the question occurred to you?

Comment: Hint: positive define matrix has positive definite square root and $AB = \sqrt{A}(\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A})(\sqrt{A})^{-1}$

Comment: @achillehui Is this a true statement?

Comment: The statement is true, $AB$ is similar to $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ which is positive definite and hence symmetric. symmetric real matrix are diagonalizable.

Comment: @achillehui not all positive matrix is invertible.

Comment: @achillehui but if $A$ is symmetric, it is true..

Comment: @kayak Actually, all positive matrices **are** invertible.  Also, I suspect that the source that you've taken this question from takes symmetry to be part of the definition of positive (semi)-definite.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh Thanks.

Comment: @achillehui Oh but $B$ is not symmetric

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, even if $B$ isn't necessarily symmetric, the same trick will work.  For a positive semidefinite matrix $B$, $XBX^T$ will be positive semidefinite for any matrix $X$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But what we try to show is not positive semidefinite, but diagonalizable. and the $XBX^{T}$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @kayak oh, right.  Well again:  I suspect that the source that you've taken this question from takes symmetry to be part of the definition of positive (semi)-definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong. $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Usually a "positive (semi) definite" matrix is assumed to be, by definition, [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). Using that definition, the OP statement is trivially true. This answer applies when we accept the more general (and less usual) definition.